# how can we select data from two or more tables if similar data is not present in both tables(without join)

Tags: sql

I need solution for this type query.Means this query is not real but I need to fetch data like this:(except `join` and `union`)

```
select a b,c
from (table1 or table2) 
where name="rohit";
```

Comment: On what basis `table1  \table2` is choose

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Comment: sql server . 
we are searching some field in two table and need to display data from both tables

Comment: An example return data set would help determine the solution.  Should each row in A be listed with each row in B, and so on?  This would then lead to all rows being repeated multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple to do with union

```
select * 
from t1
where t1.name='a' 
union (all)
select * 
from t2
where t2.name='a'
```

If union and join is not allowed you can try select both table and create kind of union via GROUP BY trick. Like this

```
select * 
from t1, t2
where t1.name='a' or t2.name='a'
group by (case t1.name 
          when 'a' then CONCAT('t1',t1.id) 
          else CONCAT('t2',t2.id) end case)
```

Haven't tested though. sqlfiddle.com somehow doesn't work showing errors when I try to execute a query like this